# get the value of table row by cliking with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a table structure like:

```
<table id= "mytable">
<body>
//first row
  <tr class = "row">
   <td id="rowTable">
     <div id="myRow1"> Part 1 </div>
     <div id="myRow2"> first </div>
     <div id="myRow3"> 123 </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
//second row
 <tr class = "row">
   <td id="rowTable">
     <div id="myRow1"> Part 2 </div>
     <div id="myRow2"> second </div>
     <div id="myRow3"> 456 </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
</body>
</table>
```

( I know the html part may seems incorrect but to be honest, I am not allowed to change it. I have to work with this structure)
And I want to read the first column of each row when I click on it by using javascript.
When I tried: `var Value = $(e.currentTarget).text();` it gave me the value of the whole row which is:

`Part 1 first 123`

but I only want the value of the first part which is `Part 1`. Any idea of how to get that value?

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child of `<tr>`. Also IDs are supposed to be uniqe. If that's your actual HTML I suggest fixing the basic structure first, adding functionality later.

Comment: To be honest, I am not allowed to change it. I have to work with this structure

Comment: @user2870274 You need to. It's complete nonsense.

Comment: so you mean I should change all the divs to td? anyway, I did it but I still get three values !

Comment: Still not good. You are using only one `td` (that denotes a column) per row and have 3 divs inside (that I suppose you think are columns). Also, you have repeated id attributes, which should be unique per element.

Comment: change the divs to spans and it's fine. You can delete the id's as you don't need them (or just ignore them).

Comment: Do you want to do this in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: you get 3 values because `currentTarget` is the td. It gives you the text of all the included divs. If you want just the div clicked on, use `e.target` instead. If you just want the first div then use `e.currentTarget.firstChild`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

### the HTML:

```
<table id= "mytable">
        <tr class = "row">
            <td id="myRow1">Part 1</td>
            <td id="myRow2">first</td>
            <td id="myRow3">123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class = "row">
            <td id="myRow1">Part 2</td>
            <td id="myRow2">second</td>
            <td id="myRow3">456</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

### the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('td').click(function(e) {
                val = e.target.innerHTML;
                //alert(val);
                //Put your code here
            });
});
```